# MSSQL: Generate Dates Between 2 Dates With Month Breaks

Tags: sql-server, datetime, intervals

Struggling a bit with this...

I have a table with the following columns:

```
Type        varchar
StartDate   datetime
EndDate     datetime
Interval    int
```

What I want is a results table with the type column and all the dates between the start date and end date, using the interval as month breaks between them.

For instance if the only row in my table is:

```
'Test', '2017-01-01', '2019-01-01', 6
```

I want a results table that has 5 rows, with 'Test' as the Type on every row, and a date column that goes from:

```
'2017-01-01', 
'2017-07-01', 
'2018-01-01', 
etc.
```

I've created a Calendar table and even a DateRange function where I pass in a start date, end date and month interval which returns me all the dates I'd want, but since it's a table-valued function I don't seem to be able to call it with data from another table.

How do I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: How are you trying to use the date range function?  Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 1):

I'll often use a TVF to create dynamic Date/Time Ranges.  A tally/calendar table will do the trick as well, but the UDF offers some additional functionality.  For example, you supply the Range, DatePart and Increment

```
Declare @YourTable table ([Type] varchar(25),StartDate date,EndDate date,Interval int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
('Test','2017-01-01','2019-01-01', 6)

Select A.[Type]
      ,B.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Range-Date](A.StartDate,A.EndDate,'MM', A.Interval) B
```

**Returns**

```
Type    RetSeq  RetVal
Test    1       2017-01-01
Test    2       2017-07-01
Test    3       2018-01-01
Test    4       2018-07-01
Test    5       2019-01-01
```

**The UDF if Interested**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Range-Date] (@R1 datetime,@R2 datetime,@Part varchar(10),@Incr int)
Returns Table
Return (
    with cte0(M)   As (Select 1+Case @Part When 'YY' then DateDiff(YY,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'QQ' then DateDiff(QQ,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MM' then DateDiff(MM,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'WK' then DateDiff(WK,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'DD' then DateDiff(DD,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'HH' then DateDiff(HH,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'MI' then DateDiff(MI,@R1,@R2)/@Incr When 'SS' then DateDiff(SS,@R1,@R2)/@Incr End),
         cte1(N)   As (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
         cte2(N)   As (Select Top (Select M from cte0) Row_Number() over (Order By (Select NULL)) From cte1 a, cte1 b, cte1 c, cte1 d, cte1 e, cte1 f, cte1 g, cte1 h ),
         cte3(N,D) As (Select 0,@R1 Union All Select N,Case @Part When 'YY' then DateAdd(YY, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'QQ' then DateAdd(QQ, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MM' then DateAdd(MM, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'WK' then DateAdd(WK, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'DD' then DateAdd(DD, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'HH' then DateAdd(HH, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'MI' then DateAdd(MI, N*@Incr, @R1) When 'SS' then DateAdd(SS, N*@Incr, @R1) End From cte2 )

    Select RetSeq = N+1
          ,RetVal = D 
     From  cte3,cte0 
     Where D<=@R2
)
/*
Max 100 million observations -- Date Parts YY QQ MM WK DD HH MI SS
Syntax:
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2016-10-01','2020-10-01','YY',1) 
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Range-Date]('2016-01-01','2017-01-01','MM',1) 
*/
```